# Are multiple queries possible with analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to retrieve many different informations from analytics for my application. My question is can I use something like

dimension1 (some metrics)
dimension2 (some other metrics).

I know, that I can make different requests, but I would like to put it all in one!

Comment: No, this isn't possible with the Core Reporting API -- if the metrics can't be applied to dimension1 and dimension2 simultaneously, then you'll need to make separate requests.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this using [Analytics Reporting API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet)

Have a look at `reportRequests` parameter in which you can pass `maximum of 5 objects`, where each object can have its own combination of dimension and metrics.

Comment: Do you maybe have some basic example of Analytics Reporting API V4?

Answer (score 0):

Make sample queries using the GA API Query Explorer here:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

See valid metric and dimension combinations here
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

Comment: How does this answer the question?